# Check for duplicate rows in 2 columns before update

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table with 4 columns, and I need to check to see if a Column Pair exists before inserting a row into the database:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCallReport_Detail (fkCallReport, fkProductCategory, Discussion, Action) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The pair in question is `fkCallReport` and `fkProductCategory`.

For example if the row trying to be inserted has `fkCallReport = 3` and `fkProductCategory = 5`, and the database already has both of those values together, it should display an error and ask 
if they would like to combine the Disuccsion and Action with the current record.

Keep in mind I'm doing this in VBA Access 2010 and am still very new.

Comment: Access is not mysql or sql-server, editing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set them both as the primary keys (compound key I believe is the correct term).  Then you'll need a unique combination to add to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

First is to make a compound primary key in the database itself.

Second is a conditional insert. Basically use `select count(*) where fkCallReport=var1 and fkProductCategory=var2` with the conditional operators of your database. MSSqL has `if` Oracle has `when` not sure about Access

If you are allowed to set up your primary keys PLEASE go with the compound key. Better practice and keeps you out of sticky situations

Comment: I think the conditional insert is what I'm looking for, but I've actually never wrote one. Would it be possible to provide a little bit more?

Comment: Something like in [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/208246-sql-using-if-then-else) should work

Answer (score 0):

You can add compound unique index on the fields fkCallReport and fkProductCategory.